# In IE6 ,What are the alternatives to display: inline-block, table, table-row. table-cell?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser

As you all know display: inline-block; doesn't work in IE6.  Amazingly, display: table, table-row, table-cell also don't work.  How can i possibly  not use tables for a complex pages?  What techniques are out there to get divs to behave like tables in IE6? In further readings/references would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume you're not displaying real tabular data, right? Also, it doesn't come across as surprising to me at all IE6's lack of support for table displays...

Comment: The best technique is not to use IE6. The second-best technique is to use actual tables instead of styled divs.

Comment: @BoltClock:  True, no tabular data, which is why i don't want to resort to using tables.

Comment: It might be useful to not describe the problem as mimicking tables and instead tell us exactly what you're trying to achieve visually along with the current markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing valid, semantic markup for layout on ie6 is a painful task, it is not impossible, here are some sources.

- [How to make it work on ie6](http://chipsandtv.com/articles/debugging-internet-explorer):a guide to the problems you'll face on ie6 and how to fix them.
- [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html): Great guide about browser support for every css declaration.
- [Cross-Browser inline-block](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/). a rather long but very thorough
  article on cross-browser `inline-block` implementation.

I hope you find them helpful.